# cannot change admin password, wordpress on godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, godaddy-api

I inherited a web task. I do not have the admin password and trying to change it in the backend via phpmyadmin.

The error I get is:

```
Incorrect password error for user admin
```

Error:

[image: error]

in wp-config, i see the following hash schema:

```
 * @since 2.6.0
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'vvvvvvvv');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'vvvvvvvv');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'vvvvvvvv');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'vvvvvvvv');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'vvvvvvvv');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'vvvvvvvv');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'vvvvvvvv');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'vvvvvvvv');
```

I create password via

http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4

and insert it into phpmyadmin with no md5 setting (since it's already hashed), just bare.

same invalid user 'admin'

DB:

[image: Database]

DBname in wp-config.php:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'i1373493_wp6');
```

and it matches the one I am editing. I'm in the correct Db and user table.

I do not have CLI access and the logs in the godaddy gui are about useless.

How do I change the WordPress admin password in godaddy?

Comment: These screenshots are really not all that helpful. Does the password value look like it uses [Modular Crypt Format](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html)? As in it starts with `$2y$...`.

Comment: You could also change the email address of the admin, then trigger a "forgot password" link to recover it that way if your mail server is correctly configured.

Comment: It sends the email but fails to send the reset link.

Comment: @tadman sample password $1$PacJv7FV$Zk7errNtaqrSVoeodJFn4/

Comment: That's using MD5 which is pretty awful considering how garbage MD5 is, but should be something you can generate and replace. Try backing up the database first, maybe even restore locally on a development copy of it, and there you can bash around and find a way that works instead of working on the live server.

Comment: You can use the password reset ... even if it doesn't send the link. Look in the database for the reset key, and then just visit the reset page `wp-login.php?action=rp&key={reset_key}&login={username}`

Comment: As @tadman suggested, you could try to take over the original admin account. Have you tried using that account by changing the email and password in the DB? Perhaps without the user info in the meta-data tables it's not working. Or somet plugin that's hooked into the log in. I would try to takeover the original admin's account. (it's possible that "admin" isn't allowed because of some silly "security" plugin)

Comment: I can't find the reset_key and I disabled the only known security plugin. repeat login attempt fail/ban. I have only tried to change the existing user password that had admin priv and then added a user named admin manually. two users only in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto PHPMYADMIN and run below commands in the SQL button.

Change username and password given in query.

INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, 
`user_status`)
 VALUES ('admin123', MD5('pass123'), 'firstname lastname', 'email@example.com', '0');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
 VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 
 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');

INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
 VALUES (NULL, (Select max(id) FROM wp_users), 'wp_user_level', '10');

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the best Solution**

You can change Your WordPress Password from setting or from your Plesk or CPanel

Step 1: Login In Your Godaddy or Hosting

Step 2: Open your Hosting Setting

Step 3: Go to The Application

Step 4: Click on Your Desire WordPress Site

Step 5: Click on Setup and change your password

Because in past I was also stuck in the same issue in my website HRO WEB DEVELOPERS